# how to check PHP array's value without index offset error in 1 IF

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to check the value of a certain key in a PHP array in 1 IF statement? Right now, in order to not throw an index offset error I have to check if the key is set, then check its value.

```
if (isset($array[$key]))
{
    if ($array[$key] == $x)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

(sorry, accidentally put ! in first IF originally)

Comment: where is the code checking value?

Comment: ok. if it is not set, then u cant check its value...

Comment: if ( isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $x)
{
   

        // do stuff
    
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `&&` operator is short-circuit](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), thus:

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $x)
    // do stuff
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: This will have errors. if it is not set than u cannot check if it is equal to something... see my answer

Comment: @Neal Thanks, but with respect, please see the comment "...ADJUST to make it correct". The short-circuit nature of `&&` still holds, this is an exercise for the poster ;-)

Comment: thanks, i didn't know && was short-circuited. "AND" is also short-circuited, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use a reference: if `$array[$key]` does not exist, then it will be created and set to null; therefore, no error will occur. This is most useful when you expect the value to exist; ie, you do not want to act specially if the value does not.

```
if (&$array[$key] == $x) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this. ur current code wont do anything bc if it is not set, the second if statement will never be...

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $x)
{
    //do stuff if that key == $x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the boolean operator `&&` ;)

```
if (isset($array[$key]) && ($array[$key] == $x)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This will have errors. if it is not set than u cannot check if it is equal to something... see my answer

Comment: Took the code from the question and didnt verified it. Of course, I should have done it.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is using `array_key_exists()` function.

An example- `array_key_exists($key,$array);`

Check the documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an associative array compare the size of array to the *key index* instead of the *$key*

```
if(sizeof($array) >= $key){

   if ($array[$key] == $x)
    {
    // do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10560732)

Comment: I think you posted this to the wrong answer mate. My answer is made of code and never had any links!

Comment: Appolgies the text was auto generated. The answer is code only and should contain some thing else to describe what's happening

Comment: The description was wrapped between "/* ... */" in the code itself. I took it of the code. Cheers